# Case when on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Table looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 PlanningID, ActivityID, 
       [This Week - 2], [This Week - 1]
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblPlanning]
```

[image]

I would like the outcome of this to be:

[image]

The code below does not give me what i want however the *CASE* expression should gives me **201814** and **201815** but it does not :/.

```
SELECT TOP 5 PlanningID,
       ActivityID,
       CASE WHEN [This Week - 2] IN ('TRUE','FALSE')-- OR  [This Week - 2] = 'FALSE'
            THEN (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120),4) +  
                              CAST((DATEPART(ISOWK,GETDATE()) - 2) AS NVARCHAR(2)))
            WHEN [This Week - 1] IN ('TRUE','FALSE')-- OR  [This Week - 1] = 'FALSE'
            THEN (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120),4) +  
                              CAST((DATEPART(ISOWK,GETDATE()) - 1) AS NVARCHAR(2)))
       END AS YearWeek
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblPlanning]
```

Do i need to use some sort of `Cross join` and how can i use `case when` for multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` operator

```
SELECT p.PlanningID, p.ActivityID,
       (CASE WHEN t.id = 2 AND t.Weeks IN (1, 0) 
             THEN '201814' WHEN t.id = 1 AND t.Weeks IN (1, 0) 
             THEN '201815' END) AS ThisWeek
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblPlanning] p 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (2, [This Week - 2]), (1, [This Week - 1])) t(Id, Weeks);
```

However, i didn't find the logic behind the `0` or `1` for your weeks columns